# PSR2 code style and PHP Code Sniffer doesn't agreed?

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpcodesniffer

I have setup my editor code style setup from `Editor > Code Style > PHP` as `Predefined Style >PSR1/PSR2`. I have PHP Code Sniffer and PHP Mess Detector installed and configured as well. Any time I format the code using `CTRL+ALT+L` I get the following issue:

[image]

Why is that? The original code looks like (I think is not so helpful but anyway here it's):

```
public function myTestFunction()
{
    $is_valid = true;

    if ($this->manual_value && !$this->_InputValidator->isValidString(
            $this->manual_value,
            1,
            2,
            Regex::STRING
        )
    ) {
        $is_valid = false;
    }

    return $is_valid;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PSR2 doesn't actually say that a multi-line IF condition needs to be indented, but PHPStorm is obviously putting in 1 indent because your lines are inside an IF condition and 1 additional indent because your lines are inside a multi-line function call.

PSR2 *does* say that multi-line function calls must be indented, but it says they must be indented *once*. That is documented here: https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md#46-method-and-function-calls

So the correct PSR2 code is probably this:

```
public function myTestFunction()
{
    $is_valid = true;

    if ($this->manual_value && !$this->_InputValidator->isValidString(
        $this->manual_value,
        1,
        2,
        Regex::STRING
    )
    ) {
        $is_valid = false;
    }

    return $is_valid;
}
```

But it doesn't look great.

What I tend to do is combine PSR2 with some multi-line condition rules from the PEAR standard, which would give you this valid PSR2 code:

```
public function myTestFunction()
{
    $is_valid = true;

    if ($this->manual_value
        && !$this->_InputValidator->isValidString(
            $this->manual_value,
            1,
            2,
            Regex::STRING
        )
    ) {
        $is_valid = false;
    }

    return $is_valid;
}
```

I have no idea if PHPStorm would agree with that, but I think it might given the indent rules it appears to have.

You can also put the `&&` at the end of the first line instead of at the start of the second. The code I posted above is just what the PEAR coding standard uses, but PSR2 doesn't define any rules for this.

Answer (score 1):

It's unfortunate; it looks like you've simply hit a bug in either your IDE's or PHPCS's interpretation of the PSR rules. One of them is wrong and is in need of a bug report being raised, but you'll need to read the PSR rules carefully to work out which one. (It may be easier to raise a bug report for both of them and let them work it out)

(I am, of course, assuming that you have the latest versions of both installed already; I note that a new release of PHPStorm has just come out, so if you haven't already upgraded, this might be a good chance to do so)

In the meanwhile, I would suggest refactoring your code to stop your `if()` statements ending up looking like that -- to be honest, it's not clean-looking code, regardless of whether it meets the PSR rules.

I would refactor it to look something like this:

```
public function myTestFunction()
{
    $input_is_valid = $this->_InputValidator->isValidString(
        $this->manual_value,
        1,
        2,
        Regex::STRING
    );

    return ($this->manual_value && !$input_is_valid);
}
```

Comment: They are not identical. The refactored version runs the is valid string function regardless. Original work only when manual value is true

Comment: @exussum You're right, and if that fact is significant then the OP may want to adjust it to suit. The refactoring part of the answer is just a suggestion as an aside, not the main answer to the original question.

Comment: @Spudley regarding the refactoring suggestion I could do that but this is not the only piece of code is just an example of a big validation function where the `$is_valid` flag is set several times